# How can I reproduce this linen print texture?

Tags: layers, photoshop-effects, drawing, texture, black

I would like to reproduce the vintage cloth book cover texture from this picture:

[image: Reference picture].

As you can see, the brown drawing and text are also textured. It contains "white dots" which makes it match the background.

When I try to reproduce the effect, it works with the background, but not with the black shapes that I paint over on a new layer. I think it's due to the lack of these "white dots".

[image: Photoshop screenshot].

How I can get the same texture effect?

Answer (score 10):

There's a lot of different tricks to achieve this.

I usually do it something like this:

Base material layer first, then all designs and on the top a copy of the material.

[image]

In the layer style panel adjust the "blend If" field to only show the darkest spots. Drag with alt key pressed to smothen transition.
[image]

So would look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The Campcraft image has plenty of low resolution imaging and JPG artifacts, but it looks like a photo of real fabric could do the job. You seem to know that.

There are whole bunch of other tricks needed to make some images and texts to look like they are on the fabric - either following its surface thickness variations or being smoother areas, maybe even having some imprint depth or thickness. As an evidence I can see some shadow at the edges of the brown areas in your Campcraft photo. An example:

[image]

The pumpkin shape and the fabric are stolen from your own attempt. There's on the top a solid brown overlay to colorize the shape below. In the middle there's a piece of desaturated fabric which has at first got a contrast boost to make it have the full scale of shades from 0 to 255. Then it has got filter Stylize > Emboss to make it look to have the fabric pattern with depth. I thought it should resemble some not fully matte paint. Emboss creates as well glosses and shadows for it. The plain mid layer is this:

[image]

It has also torn edges to make it look less clinical. Actually the edges are distorted with a displacement map which was made from fabric by increasing the contrast.

Finally the top layer has got layer style Bevel&Emboss to make it look it's thick. But the fabric background looks a little puny when compared to the pumpkin. As a quick fix I inserted an embossed copy of it to make the fabric also to have some depth:

[image]

It cannot have as much contrast as the painted area because the fabric very likely isn't glossy. That's why there's inserted a separate layer.

You may be happy with a simpler version. The next is what I consider the minimum:

[image]

The pumpkin layer and the fabric have got the same texture shading from the top layer. The top layer is the fabric layer which is desaturated, lifted to full contrast range with curves and finally embossed. Stylize > Emboss makes the average brightness to 50% which is perfect for using blending mode Hard Light to transfer the shading to the image below.